# How to mix Razor with string literals in HTML helpers for asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Quote Number: "@item.QuoteNumber,
    actionName: "MyAction",
    controllerName: "Home",
)
```

I'm trying to do something as above to append the item quote number the literal label. `QuoteNumber` is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following

```
@Html.ActionLink( linkText: string.Format("Quote Number: {0}",item.QuoteNumber), actionName: "MyAction", controllerName: "Home")
```

and if  you want to pass values

```
@Html.ActionLink(string.Format("Quote Number: {0}",item.QuoteNumber), "MyAction","Home", new {id = item.QuoteNumber})
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

You are in C#, so you can just append the strings. Something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Quote Number: " + item.QuoteNumber,
    actionName: "MyAction",
    controllerName: "Home"
)
```